# Why don't changes to my padding affect the width of an element in IE?

Tags: html, css

Firefox and Chrome are handling padding in a different way from IE.

For Firefox and Chrome, when I use padding, this is added to the total width of the div. For IE, padding values are ignored so the CSS doesn't work uniformly. This seems to be a new development because they've always worked the same. EG

```
#header
{
   width:280;
   padding-left:10px;
   padding-right:10px;
}
```

This gives a total of 300px in Firefox and Chrome but the width doesn't change in IE.

How do I handle this issue?

Comment: what is the HTML you're trying to style. The element makes a difference, as it could be using a different box model, or display mode depending on the browser.

Comment: See this [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug)...

Comment: Which IE's are you targeting, by the way?

Answer (score 1):

What you're dealing with here is a [known problem in IE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug).

In short, when there's a problem with your HTML, IE drops into Quirks Mode as it tries to figure out how to resolve those problems. When it does this, its interpretation of the [CSS Box Model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html) (the thing that determines how to handle width, padding, border and margin) breaks away from the W3C standard.

So, odds are, there's a problem with your HTML and your first port of call should be the [W3C Markup Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/). Use this to validate your HTML. Once your HTML validates, try again with your CSS. If it's still broken, head back here.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a doctype and modifying my html tag helped me fix the problem. This is the new change below.

```
DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd" 

html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en"
```

Of course, I used opening and closing tags but there's not displaying properly as code blocks